# Changing the spacing between files in ls

Tags: osx, ls

This is more of a cosmetic question but this is really bugging me.  On OS X, when I run `ls -G` (or use CLICOLOR=1) instead of regular `ls` it changes the spacing of the columns, as you can see in this picture:

[image: ls vs ls -G spacing]

Is there a way to change the spacing so that running `ls -G` produces the same spacing seen in the regular `ls`?

*Edit

CLICOLOR NOT SET:
[image: CLICOLOR=0]

CLICOLOR=1
[image: CLICOLOR=1]

**NOTE:** from the `ls` man page on OSX

```
-G      Enable colorized output.  This option is equivalent to defining 
        CLICOLOR in the environment.  (See below.)
```

Comment: Looking at the source in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-242/ls/ it looks like enabling colors sets `f_notabs`, since it doesn't want to use hard tabs in combination with ANSI erscape sequences, but this also sets `tabwidth` to 1 (it would otherwise be 8), which increases the number of available columns. I don't see a way to change this short of altering the source code.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Have you found any solution in five years? The problem still exists.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe A workaround might be to use Homebrew to install GNU coreutils, and use its GNU ls. See the answers to the question  [How to replace Mac OS X utilities with GNU core utilities](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of OSX & the various tools you are using but I have the following setup on my OSX system and `ls -G` shows the same column alignments as the vanilla `ls`.

#### Examples

[image: ss#1]

My setup consist of the following environment variables.

```
$ env|grep -Ei "cli|ls|col"
TERM=xterm-256color
CLICOLOR=1
LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

Comment: It is a fresh install of OS X Yosemite with no environment variables set save for `PS1="\t:\w\$ "`.  In the screenshot, CLICOLOR is disabled.  However, with CLICOLOR enabled, `ls` produces the same spacing that `ls -G` produces in the screenshot.

Comment: @AlexW. - so then what's the issue? If you set that variable all is right, no?

Comment: No. When I said that `CLICOLOR=1` produces the same spacing that `ls -G` produces with `CLICOLOR=0`, I mean that it is still changing the spacing of `ls`.  You can see this clearly in the output of `ls`.  With `CLICOLOR` disabled, the result is two rows of items whereas `CLICOLOR=1` will produce only the one row. See the new screenshots I added for clarity.

Comment: @AlexW. - OK, thanks for the update in the Q. What terminal emulator are you using here? I've replicated my tests in iTerm, Terminal, and SSH'ed into the box from a Linux box. The `ls -G` output I show is consistent on all three.

Comment: It's the OS X default terminal, using the "Pro" default profile.

Comment: @AlexW. - that's what I have as well.

Comment: If CLICOLOR is present in the environment, `ls` will behave as if it had been given a -G option. It doesn't even look at the value of CLICOLOR; the value could be "0", "1", or even "", with the same results. The code to process -G actually does nothing more than `setenv("CLICOLOR","",1)`.

Comment: @slm I have the same problem as OP on at least two macbooks.